# Clickable event in JavaScript in orde to display an image

Tags: javascript

So I have a photo gallery that contains photo's in a thumbnail, and one big image. When the user clicks the thumbnail, it should display the thumbnail image larger. Everything else is done but I can't get the JS to work. I know it's something small, so can someone take a look at and see what I am doing incorrectly? Thank you in advance.

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv = "X-UA-Compatible" content = "IE=edge">
    <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale = 1">

    <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "html5reset.css">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "gallery.css">


</head>

<body>

    <div class = "main">

        <div class = "wrapper">

            <div id = "largeImage">

        <img src = "images/machine_1.jpg" alt = "machining image" width = "920" height = "400" id = "bigImage" class = "border"/>

            </div>

            <div class = "thumbnail">

              <img src="images/machine_1.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_1"/>
              <img src="images/machine_2.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_2"/>
              <img src="images/machine_3.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_3"/>
              <img src="images/machine_4.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_4"/>
              <img src="images/machine_5.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_5"/>
              <img src="images/machine_6.jpg" alt = "machining lathe"  id="machine_6"/>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src = "gallery.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

```js
function imgFunction() {

    var bigImage = document.getElementById("bigImage");
    var thumbnail = document.getElementById("thumbnail");

    thumbnail.addEventListener("click",function(event) {

        if (event.target.tagName == "IMG") {
            bigImage.src = event.target.src;
        }
    },false);
}

window.addEventListener("load", imgFunction, false);
```

Comment: Are you getting an error? Have you done `console.log(event)` or `console.log(event.target)` to make sure you're getting the right element? What have you done to try and debug this?

Comment: You have no elements with `id="thumbnail"` so `document.getElementById("thumbnail")` will not resolve anything.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to select your `<div class="thumbnail">` but you use `getElementById`.

So just give your div the id: `<div id="thumbnail">`.

Answer (score 3):

**JQuery Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#3aa0ea4a91d84cfd35f0b8b4151499bc
**Plain JS Weave:** http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#21d2b4bd5fa4c388d7e63c34ea23f4cd

Your main problem is you're calling `document.getElementById("thumbnail")` and no `#thumbnail` exists in your html.

So either change...

```
document.getElementById("thumbnail")
```

to

```
document.querySelector(".thumbnail")
```

or

to

```
<div id="thumbnail">
```

[Here's a JQuery solution.](http://kodeweave.sourceforge.net/editor/#3aa0ea4a91d84cfd35f0b8b4151499bc)

```js
var thumbnail = document.querySelector('.thumbnails');
var preview   = document.querySelector('.preview');

thumbnail.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == "IMG") {
    preview.src = e.target.src;
  }
}, false);
```

```css
.gallery {
  text-align: center;
}

.preview {
  width: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.thumbnails {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: auto;
}

.thumbnails img {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <img src="http://www.catersnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1_CATERS_BEAR_HANDSHAKE_07-800x498.jpg" class="preview">
  
  <div class="thumbnails">
    <img src="http://www.catersnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/1_CATERS_BEAR_HANDSHAKE_07-800x498.jpg">
    <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/9a/44/23/9a4423324fe1fcc23c436a91ad4c9667.jpg">
    <img src="http://www.earthtouchnews.com/media/734889/Baby_bears_2014-11-25.jpg">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/wYFHJNI.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```